# matplotlib рисует лишние горизонтальные линии

Tags: python, matplotlib

Хочу вывести несколько тестовых линий на экран следующим образом:

```
_fig = plt.figure()
_axs = _fig.subplots()

_axs.plot(xf, data_first['temperature'], ':')
_axs.plot(xf, data_first['velocity'], ':')

_axs.plot(xl, data_last['temperature'])
_axs.plot(xl, data_last['velocity'])
```

Собираюсь проследить изменения, где `data_first` и `xf` - пунктирные линии, `data_last` и `xl` - сплошные.

`data_first` и `data_last` - словари с идентичной структурой

```
{'prop1': [float, float, float, ...], 'prop2': [float, float, float, ...], ...}
```

Пытаюсь нарисовать несколько линий, используя список строк `prop_list` (соотвественно, `prop_list = ['temperature', 'velocity']`):

```
for prop in prop_list:
    _subplot.plot(xf, [data_first[prop]], ':', color=colors[prop]),
    _subplot.plot(xl, [data_last[prop]], '-', color=colors[prop], label=prop),
```

В обоих случаях получаю (без приближения и с ним):

[image: без приближения]
[image: с приближением]

Подозреваю, что эти горизонтальные линии появляются из-за разных xf и xl, но хочу узнать, можно ли обойтись без twiny()

Comment: А что в `xf` и `xl`?

Comment: float'ы от 0 до 360, в одном около 1900 значений, в другом примерно 1600

Comment: А значения в них отсортированы? Проверьте. Похоже на то, как будто в конце у вас там нули, например, и получается линия назад к отправной точке.

Comment: Да, отсортированы. Оказалось, в `xl` случайно попадает последнее значение из `xf`, поэтому там получился список [359.99, 0, 0.01, 0.03, 0.04 и т.д.]
Теперь графики строятся как надо, спасибо

Comment: Можете тогда оформить сами ответ на свой вопрос - написать там в чём было дело и как вы исправили. Может кому потом пригодится.